# How to autofill data in google sheets based on values in a column in two different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I have two columns Id and Name. I want to be able to either fill the Id or Name and the other one is autofilled based on values I have in another sheet.

I'm able to autofill only one of the columns with VLOOKUP function, but once I try to do it in the other column is doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: vlookup with array can do, share a sample trix and what you want to achieve

Comment: with `vlookup` it is possible. another way would be to use `query`

Comment: Please share your sheet

Comment: Hi, here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XrhGL-NlB48Gt57ZrGFErOeh8TVkWMcomHxZ-p1tLb0/edit?usp=sharing
Want I'm trying to achieve is having if I insert id, then name is automatically filled and if I insert name then id will be filled.

Comment: If you want to do this so that ID is automatically populated when Name changes *and* vice versa, then you need a script rather than just sheets formulae. Would this be an acceptable solution for you?